# Word search in Excel files

Tags: excel, powershell, search, report

I found a PowerShell code that finds the word I want in excel files in a folder and reports it. I made some changes. but I am getting some errors. Error "_FilterDatabase", file path longer than 255 characters. There was also the problem of opening encrypted files, I solved it.

I'm pretty new to using PowerShell. Can you guide me to fix these errors?

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
Function Search-Excel {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({
            Try {
                If (Test-Path -Path $_) { $True }
                Else { Throw "$($_) hatalı adres" }
            }
            Catch {
                Throw $_
            }
        })]
        [string]$Source,
        
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$SearchText
        #You can specify wildcard characters (*, ?)
        ) 
    
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Files = Get-Childitem $Source -Include *.xlsx,*.xls -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }
    $sayi = 0

    $sifreli = @()
    $Fullsifre = Get-ChildItem $Source -Include *.xlsx*, *.xls* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $sifreList = select-string -pattern "<encryption" $Fullsifre 
    
    foreach ($sifrelimi in $sifreList) {
        $sifreli = $sifreli + $sifrelimi.Path
    } 

    Foreach ($File In $Files)
    {

        $sayi=$sayi + 1
        Write-Host "$sayi - $file - isimli dosyaya bakılıyor..."

        If($File -in $sifreli){

        write-host "$File dosyası şifrelidir"
        }
        else {

            Try {
                $Source = Convert-Path $File
            }
            Catch {
                Write-Warning "Unable locate full path of $($Source)"
                BREAK
            }
            $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File,$null,$true)
            ForEach ($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Sheets)) {
                # Find Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel
                $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText) #What
                If ($Found) {
                    # Address Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel
                    $BeginAddress = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
                    
                    #Initial Found Cell
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        'Dosya Yolu' = $File.FullName
                        'Sayfa' = $Worksheet.Name
                        'Sutun' = $Found.Column
                        'Satır' =$Found.Row
                        'Bulunan Metin' = $Found.Text
                        'Konum' = $BeginAddress
                    }
                    
                    Do {
                        $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.FindNext($Found)
                        if($Found -eq $null){
                            write-host -ForegroundColor green  "değerboş"
                            BREAK
                        }

                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "burada               $Found.                 hatalı ne var"
                        $Address = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "burada               $Address                 hatalı ne var"
                        
                        If ($Address -eq $BeginAddress) {
                            write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "BREAK OLDUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU"
                            BREAK
                        }
                        
                        [pscustomobject]@{
                            'Dosya Yolu' = $File.FullName
                            'Sayfa' = $Worksheet.Name
                            'Sutun' = $Found.Column
                            'Satır' =$Found.Row
                            'Bulunan Metin' = $Found.Text
                            'Konum' = $Address
                        }
                    } Until ($False)
                }
                Else {
                    Write-Warning "[$($WorkSheet.Name)] Nothing Found!"
                }
            }
            
            $workbook.close($false)
        }
    }
    
    [void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$excel)
    [gc]::Collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Remove-Variable excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}


$folders = 
Get-ChildItem \\computername\log | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

$say = 0
Foreach ($bul In $folders) {
    $say = $say + 1
    Write-Host "$say - $bul klasöründe Telefon kelimesi aranıyor..."
    [String]$outfile = "\\computername\rapor\$bul" + "-excel-" + (Get-Date).tostring("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".csv"

    Search-Excel -Source "\\computername\log\$bul" -SearchText Telefon | Export-Csv -Path $outfile -Encoding UTF8
}
```

"error message"

> Unable to get Open property of Workbooks class
> At line:52 char:1

- $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File,$null,$true)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

The property 'Cells' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property e
xists.
At line:55 char:1

- $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText) #What
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
  ```

The invoked object is separated from its clients. (HRESULT exception returned: 0x800101
08 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
At line:95 char:1

- $workbook.close($false)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

Comment: Any reason why you're using COM object vs the [ImportExcel Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0)?

Comment: no. Since I am new, I am trying to do something by looking at the codes I found on the net.

Comment: It gives the error "Unable to get Open property of Workbooks class At line:52 char:1" when it encounters an error in the loop.

Comment: `Get-Childitem` returns **objects**. Excel need a full filepath, so `$Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName,$null,$true)`

Comment: @teo thanks, Also, the search for empty folders was returning an error. I made an edit about it. if folder is empty i added loop